# I want to execute a statement according to the condition of the received UDP data

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp

I have uploaded the translated text. The explanation is not clear.
So I add the content.

I want to handle the received HEX data.
code :

```
server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(msg)
  console.log(msg[0]+" "+msg[1]+" "+msg[2])
  console.log(`server got: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}\n`);
});
```

output:

```
<Buffer 42 41 42 43 41>
66 65 66
server got: BABCA from 127.0.0.1:58107
```

If the 1st~3rd argument of the 'msg' variable is 41 41 42 (hex), console.log("Success");

I wanted to ask this.
What should I do?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/dgram.html#udpdatagram-sockets

Comment: Please show us the code you have for receiving the UDP data and we can show you how to output it.

Comment: It is unclear for me what your problem is. Inability to receive UDP packets? Inability to display content as hex? Something else

Comment: Perhaps `console.log(msg.toString('utf8'))` if the data is ascii or utf8 characters.  Still not really sure what you're asking for help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to output Success if the 1st to 3rd arguments are 41 41 42 in hexadecimal, respectively. I want to write this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using buffers and converting values to strings using console.log() you have to be careful of encoding issues. When you `console.log()` the first byte of msg, Node displays the ASCII value of it. To see the hex value, you need to convert the byte to its hex value using `toString(16)`. This tells node to display the base 16 (hex) value of the byte.

```
const msg = Buffer.from('4241424341', 'hex');

console.log(msg);
console.log('Hex encode first byte of msg: ' + msg.toString('hex',0,1));
console.log('ASCII encode first byte of msg: ' + msg.toString('ascii',0,1));
console.log('Hex of msg[0]: ' + msg[0].toString(16));
console.log('ASCII code of msg[0]: ' + msg[0]);

const firstThree = msg.slice(0, 3);
const compareBuffer = Buffer.from('424142', 'hex');

console.log(firstThree);
console.log(compareBuffer)

const isSuccess = compareBuffer.equals(firstThree);
console.log(isSuccess);
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to output Success if the 1st to 3rd arguments are 41 41 42 in hexadecimal, respectively. I want to write this logic.

```
if (msg[0] === 0x41 && msg[1] === 0x41 && msg[2] === 0x42) {
    console.log("Success");
}
```

Or, since these particular values you are comparing to correspond to ascii character codes, you could also do this:

```
if (msg.toString('ascii', 0, 3) === "AAB") {
    console.log("Success");
}
```

Comment: This solution uses literal encoding of the hex values.

Comment: I have one more question.
If I want to retransmit the 3rd~5th argument of msg as it is, how should I write the code?

Comment: @Sliced_ice take a look at the code in my answer. You'll see how I grab the first three bytes. You can use the same slice method to pull out any bytes and then send them back to the client.

Comment: @Sliced_ice - You can use `msg.slice(2, 5)` (see [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufslicestart-end) for `.slice()`) to create a new buffer that contains those three bytes and then use your UDP interface for sending that data.  You could also use `Buffer.alloc()` and `msg.copy()` to create a new buffer and copy data into it.